Unable to resolve the Azure Storage connection named 'AzureWebJobsStorage' when running my docker image
I have an application that uses azure durable functions, it works very well locally, but when I containerized this app, and I run my image I get this error: Unable to resolve the Azure Storage connection named 'AzureWebJobsStorage'.
Here's what I tested :

I have the "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=..." set in my local.settings.json file.
I have the "AzureWebJobsStorage" and "AzureWebJobsDashboard" set in the azure app settings with the same connection string as the local.settings.json file.
I added this in host.json file:

  "extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
      "hubName": "MyTaskHub",
      "storageProvider": {
        "connectionStringName": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
      }
    }
  },


I checked the indentation and commas in the two JSON files I mentioned, everything looks okay.
I restarted the function app.
I've read several forums and articles but the solutions are always the same (what I mentioned).

But nothing worked :(
Your help would be really appreciated, thank you !
Edit :
I mounted the local.settings.json file when i run the image, because indeed, as the file is in the dockerignore file then it is not found in the container, unless you mount it in volume, which I found logical because the application had no connection string at hand, but nothing, it doesn't work either,   I really don't understand why, am I skipping something important?

I think would be good to share the code related to the containerizing the application.

I got the same error when I tried running Containerized Python Azure Durable function.

To resolve this error, pass the storage connection string as an environment variable called AzureWebJobsStorage to the docker run command.

docker run -p 8080:80 -it -e AzureWebJobsStorage="<Storage_connection_string>" <Image_name>:tag

or set the Storage_account as ARG and pass it as environment variable in Docker file.
Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.11

ARG STORAGE_ACCOUNT
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true \
AzureWebJobsStorage=$STORAGE_ACCOUNT

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot


Command to run the Image:

1. docker build --build-arg STORAGE_ACCOUNT='<storage_connection_string>' -t <Image_name> .
2. docker run -p 8080:80 <Image_name>


Created a python durable function with docker:
func init --docker
func new

local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
  }
}


Able to run the docker Image successfully:

(.venv) C:\Users\uname\pydf>docker run -p 8080:80 -it -e AzureWebJobsStorage="<Storage_connection_string>" pravallikakv/pydf
info: Host.Triggers.DurableTask[0]
      Using the default storage provider: AzureStorage.
info: Host.Triggers.Warmup[0]
      Initializing Warmup Extension.
info: Host.Triggers.DurableTask[0]
      Durable extension configuration loaded: {"httpSettings":{"defaultAsyncRequestSleepTimeMilliseconds":30000},"hubName":"TestHubName","storageProvider":{"connectionName":null,"connectionStringName":null,"controlQueueBatchSize":32,"partitionCount":4,"controlQueueBufferThreshold":256,"controlQueueVisibilityTimeout":"00:05:00","workItemQueueVisibilityTimeout":"00:05:00","trackingStoreConnectionName":null,"trackingStoreConnectionStringName":null,"trackingStoreNamePrefix":null,"fetchLargeMessagesAutomatically":true,"maxQueuePollingInterval":"00:00:30","useLegacyPartitionManagement":false,"useTablePartitionManagement":false},"tracing":{"traceInputsAndOutputs":false,"allowVerboseLinuxTelemetry":false,"traceReplayEvents":false,"distributedTracingEnabled":false,"distributedTracingProtocol":"HttpCorrelationProtocol","version":"V1"},"notifications":{"eventGrid":null},"maxConcurrentActivityFunctions":80,"maxConcurrentOrchestratorFunctions":80,"localRpcEndpointEnabled":null,"maxEntityOperationBatchSize":5000,"extendedSessionsEnabled":false,"extendedSessionIdleTimeoutInSeconds":30,"maxOrchestrationActions":100000,"overridableExistingInstanceStates":"NonRunningStates","entityMessageReorderWindowInMinutes":30,"useGracefulShutdown":false,"rollbackEntityOperationsOnExceptions":true,"throwStatusExceptionsOnRaiseEvent":null,"useAppLease":true,"storeInputsInOrchestrationHistory":false,"appLeaseOptions":{"renewInterval":"00:00:25","acquireInterval":"00:05:00","leaseInterval":"00:01:00"}}. HubName: TestHubName. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 2.12.0.
info: Host.Triggers.DurableTask[0]
      Opened local http RPC endpoint: http://127.0.0.1:17071/durabletask/. InstanceId: . Function: . HubName: TestHubName. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 2.12.0. SequenceNumber: 0.
info: Host.Startup[503]
      Initializing Host. OperationId: '170705c0-6b98-4333-a11c-45e3a13ce129'.
info: Host.Startup[504]
      Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1, OperationId=170705c0-6b98-4333-a11c-45e3a13ce129
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      LoggerFilterOptions
      {
        "MinLevel": "None",
        "Rules": [
          {
            "ProviderName": null,
            "CategoryName": null,
            "LogLevel": null,
            "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
          },
          {
            "ProviderName": null,
            "CategoryName": "Host.Function.ToolingConsoleLog",
            "LogLevel": "Information",
            "Filter": null
          },
          {
            "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",       
            "CategoryName": null,
            "LogLevel": "None",
            "Filter": null
          },
          {
            "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",       
            "CategoryName": null,
            "LogLevel": null,
            "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
          }
        ]
      }
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      LanguageWorkerOptions
      {
        "WorkerConfigs": [
          {
            "Description": {
              "Language": "python",
              "DefaultRuntimeName": null,
              "DefaultRuntimeVersion": "3.11",
              "SupportedArchitectures": [
                "X64",
                "X86",
                "Arm64"
              ],
              "SupportedOperatingSystems": [
                "LINUX",
                "OSX",
                "WINDOWS"
              ],
              "SupportedRuntimeVersions": [
                "3.7",
                "3.8",
                "3.9",
                "3.10",
                "3.11"
              ],
              "SanitizeRuntimeVersionRegex": null,
              "WorkerIndexing": "true",
              "Extensions": [
                ".py"
              ],
              "UseStdErrorStreamForErrorsOnly": false,
              "DefaultExecutablePath": "python",
              "DefaultWorkerPath": "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.11/LINUX/X64/worker.py",
              "WorkerDirectory": "/azure-functions-host/workers/python",
              "Arguments": [],
              "WorkerArguments": null
            },
            "Arguments": {
              "ExecutablePath": "python",
              "ExecutableArguments": [],
              "WorkerPath": "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.11/LINUX/X64/worker.py",
              "WorkerArguments": []
            },
            "CountOptions": {
              "SetProcessCountToNumberOfCpuCores": false,
              "ProcessCount": 1,
              "MaxProcessCount": 10,
              "ProcessStartupInterval": "00:00:10",
              "ProcessStartupTimeout": "00:01:00",
              "InitializationTimeout": "00:00:10",
              "EnvironmentReloadTimeout": "00:00:30",
              "ProcessRestartInterval": "00:00:10",
              "ProcessShutdownTimeout": "00:00:10"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      ConcurrencyOptions
      {
        "DynamicConcurrencyEnabled": false,
        "MaximumFunctionConcurrency": 500,
        "CPUThreshold": 0.8,
        "SnapshotPersistenceEnabled": true
      }
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      FunctionResultAggregatorOptions
      {
        "BatchSize": 1000,
        "FlushTimeout": "00:00:30",
        "IsEnabled": true
      }
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      SingletonOptions
      {
        "LockPeriod": "00:00:15",
        "ListenerLockPeriod": "00:01:00",
        "LockAcquisitionTimeout": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807",
        "LockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:05",
        "ListenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00"
      }
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      ScaleOptions
      {
        "ScaleMetricsMaxAge": "00:02:00",
        "ScaleMetricsSampleInterval": "00:00:10",
        "MetricsPurgeEnabled": true,
        "IsTargetScalingEnabled": true,
        "IsRuntimeScalingEnabled": false
      }
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.JobHostService[0]
      Starting JobHost
info: Host.Startup[401]
      Starting Host (HostId=907ed61a64ca-2137340777, InstanceId=69317c69-6d0f-4c7d-b241-725fc03fe0fb, Version=4.31.1.1, ProcessId=9, AppDomainId=1, InDebugMode=False, InDiagnosticMode=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=(null))
info: Host.Startup[314]
      Loading functions metadata
info: Host.Startup[326]
      Reading functions metadata (Custom)
info: Host.Startup[327]
      1 functions found (Custom)
info: Host.Startup[315]
      3 functions loaded
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Generating 3 job function(s)
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcFunctionInvocationDispatcher[0]
      Worker process started and initialized.
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Found the following functions:
      Host.Functions.DurableFunctionsHttpStart
      Host.Functions.DurableFunctionsOrchestrator
      Host.Functions.Hello

info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      HttpOptions
      {
        "DynamicThrottlesEnabled": false,
        "EnableChunkedRequestBinding": false,
        "MaxConcurrentRequests": -1,
        "MaxOutstandingRequests": -1,
        "RoutePrefix": "api"
      }
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebScriptHostHttpRoutesManager[0]
      Initializing function HTTP routes
      Mapped function route 'api/orchestrators/{functionName}' [post,get] to 'DurableFunctionsHttpStart'     

info: Host.Startup[412]
      Host initialized (229ms)
info: Host.Triggers.DurableTask[0]
      Starting task hub worker. Extension GUID d96ae2fc-98f4-4254-a8cd-e4a60434cb7b. InstanceId: . Function: . HubName: TestHubName. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 2.12.0. SequenceNumber: 1.
info: Host.Triggers.DurableTask[0]
      Task hub worker started. Latency: 00:00:01.7470632. Extension GUID d96ae2fc-98f4-4254-a8cd-e4a60434cb7b. InstanceId: . Function: . HubName: TestHubName. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 2.12.0. SequenceNumber: 2.
info: Host.Startup[413]
      Host started (2055ms)
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Job host started
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /azure-functions-host
Now listening on: http://[::]:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Host.General[337]
      Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000001F8FC5BA'.

References:
https://medium.com/@cmendibl3/run-a-durable-azure-function-in-a-container-d0844fec765a

Thank you very much for your detailed answer and your effort, I just want to know one thing, when you pass the connection string as an environment variable can't other people access it? I need to deploy my application to Azure for it to be in production. It's safer to put it in run command than to put it in dockerfile, right?

Yes, you can directly pass it in the command.

Great, i'm gonna try that.

@Lydia You should consider accessing from Azure Keyvault instead
